# What does "Markup should be rigorous" mean?

Tags: terminology, markup, iso, sgml

The [ISO definition of generalized markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) states:

> Markup should be rigorous so that the techniques available for processing rigorously-defined objects like programs and databases can be used for processing documents as well.

What does "rigorous" mean in this context?

I found [a paper](http://www.sgmlsource.com/history/AnnexA.htm) which says:

> ...the type definition and the marked up document together [...] constitute the rigorously described document that machine processing requires.

...but I'm still unclear on the exact definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**rigorous**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rigorous) (comparative more rigorous, superlative most rigorous)
>
> 1. Manifesting, exercising, or favoring rigour; allowing no abatement or mitigation; scrupulously accurate; exact; strict; severe; relentless; as, a rigorous officer of justice; a rigorous execution of law; a rigorous definition or demonstration.

I.e., the rules for a markup language should be specified in such a way as to leave no ambiguity and no doubt as to their interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Rigorous XML for instance just means valid XML that follows all the markup rules.